# Separate 2 indicator / One script

Tags: pine-script

How can i separate my RSI to my other indicator on 1 script
I want to put rsi below the graph (in separate window at his place) and my other one on the graph with candles

I test with overlay =true and false and it just moove both together

Thanks mates

For a look i don't want that, i want rsi below on a new window

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crn4A.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that with Pinescript
We can't with 1 script create multiple windows/panes
You'll have to create 2 indicators here - 1 per "window/pane"